# Send an array of php ajax data

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to send PHP an array via AJAX. While I understand that I must use JSON, the problem comes when trying to send an additional variable from JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mostrardatossinllamada(pagina) {
        var numfilas = 9;
        var paginasamostrar = 8;
        var num_pagina=pagina;
        //var personasjs=new Array();

        // Envio el array de personas a la vista tabla_usuario_prueba_2 que me muestra los resultados paginados
        var personasjs=<?php echo json_encode($persona) ?>
        var dato=7;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo site_url("archivo/modelo_tabla"); ?>',
            data: {'pagina':num_pagina, 'personas':personasjs },

            success: function (resp) {
                $("#tablaUsuarios").html(resp);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

In my controller, I catch result but it does not work.

```
$personas = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['personas']));
```

Te code error - Severity: Warning

Message: stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Output of `json_encode($persona)`?

Answer (score -1):

Try this one. I have added the **dataType: 'json'** property.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mostrardatossinllamada(pagina) {
        var numfilas = 9;
        var paginasamostrar = 8;
        var num_pagina=pagina;
        //var personasjs=new Array();

        // Envio el array de personas a la vista tabla_usuario_prueba_2 que me muestra los resultados paginados
        var personasjs=<?php echo json_encode($persona) ?>
        var dato=7;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo site_url("archivo/modelo_tabla"); ?>',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'pagina':num_pagina, 'personas':personasjs },

            success: function (resp) {
                $("#tablaUsuarios").html(resp);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The success function is expecting the response to be a string of HTML. Telling jQuery to treat it as a JSON data structure seems counterproductive.

Comment: dataType: json should be dataType: 'json', otherwise you're passing `undefined` as dataType.

Comment: @RubenVincenten — Wouldn't it be throwing a Reference Error and aborting the program?

Comment: @RubenVicenten - ReferenceError: mostrardatossinllamada is not defined

Comment: hence why I suggested making it a string :)

Comment: code error - Severity: Warning

Message: stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Please post the output as var_dump here

Comment: var_dump($personas):  NULL

Comment: What is about var_dump($_POST)?

Comment: OK ! 
Collects data without 'json_decode' ! Only $_POST[$personas]